# Undetermined Coefficient for 2 first order differential equation.

Tags: differential

I could not understand the textbook clearly.

When you are trying to find a particular solution of

x' = -2x + y + 2e^(-t)

y' = x -2y + 3t

I understand that 2e^(-t) would have a form of a*t*e^-t + b*e^-t

in which a and b needs to be determined and

3t would have a form of c*t + d

However, the book all the sudden subbed it into differential equation

and just says, "we obtain the following algebraic equations for a,b,c and d:"

Aa = -a

Ab = a - b - (2 0)' (' is transpose)

Ac = - (0 3)'

Ad = c

in x' = Ax + g(t) where A is the constant matrix and g(t) is particular solution.

Anyhow can anyone please show me how to solve

undetermined coefficient for 2 first order differential equation with steps?

Comment: Any help would be appreciated, spent too much trying to figure out what the textbook is trying to say..

Answer (score 2):

You are given:

$$x' = -2x + y + 2e^{-t} \\ y' = x -2y + 3t$$

This can be written as:

$$X'(t) = \begin{bmatrix}x'(t)\\y'(t)\end{bmatrix} = AX(t) + F(t) = \begin{bmatrix}-2 & 1\\1 & -2\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x(t)\\y(t)\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}2e^{-t}\\ 3t \end{bmatrix}$$

Do you know how to approach solving this?

For the matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix}-2 & 1\\1 & -2\end{bmatrix}$, we find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors and end up with the general solution of the homogenous system as:

$$X_h(t) = c_1 \begin{bmatrix} 1\\-1\end{bmatrix}e^{-3t} + c_2 \begin{bmatrix} 1\\1\end{bmatrix}e^{-t}$$

Now, we can decompose $F(t)$ as:

$$F(t) =  \begin{bmatrix} 2\\0\end{bmatrix}e^{-t} + \begin{bmatrix} 0\\3\end{bmatrix}t$$

Do you see how we do that?

Since we have the term $e^{-t}$ in the homogeneous solution, we have to multiply what we have for the particular solution by $t$. Are you clear of this from the Method of Undetermined Coefficients?

So, we assume that:

$$X_p(t) = v(t) = a t e^{-t} + be^{-t} + c t + d$$

Where $a, b, c$ and $d$ are **vectors** to be determined.

I will get you started with the first one and you can do the others.

We have:

$$x' = ae^{-t} - ate^{-t} - be^{-t} + c = Ax + F = A(a t e^{-t} + be^{-t} + c t + d) +  \begin{bmatrix} 2\\0\end{bmatrix}e^{-t} + \begin{bmatrix} 0\\3\end{bmatrix}t$$

If we equate the terms on the left and right (start with the term $te^{-t}$), we have:

$$Aa = -a$$

Now, you have three other terms to equate and derive the three other expressions shown.

Comment: Not really....I thought if would be matching the coefficients. For example, a1*te^-t + b1*e^-t with 2e^-t but this would take too long.

Comment: I can solve it using variation of parameter or diagonalization in this case but not sure how to solve using undetermined coefficient.

Comment: I understand, personally I think variation of parameter is much more efficient.